# CentOS postfix smtp server connection refused from outside

Tags: centos, postfix, firewall, smtp, port

I am quite stuck with my postfix/smtp configuration on my CentOS machine.

I setup a mail dns mail.domain.tld, configured in the postfix main.conf file and tested
locally on the server by connecting to

$telent mail.domain.tld 25

This gives me a response and it's possible to send e-mails from the mail server it self.
Now, I want to use the mail server in my e-mail client but I cant get a connection with the server, if i test a telnet connection from my local desktop it's been refused by the server.

I know this should be something like a firewall, there is iptables running but I added ports to be accepted, I added + saved + restarted iptables but no port 25 or 587 (also configured from the postfix master.conf) wont work from outside the server.

(telnet 587 also not working from the server locally).

```
# lsof -ni tcp:25
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
master  27179 root   12u  IPv4 52473467      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
master  27179 root   13u  IPv6 52473469      0t0  TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)

# netstat -an | grep LIST
...    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
...   


# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp
```

I can deliver more outputs if needed!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your local ISP filter outgoing port 25?

Comment: Check that the line starting with submission is uncommented in /etc/postfix/master.cf

Comment: I fixed by taking over it to port 578! like Gabriel talavera says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be sending *outgoing* mail from your desktop on port 587, the submission port, not port 25 (which is meant for transferring mail *between* SMTP servers). Make sure your `/etc/postfix/master.cf` has the `submission` section enabled.